# Update any column in target table with corresponding non-null source field

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, merge

This is probably a familiar problem but i didn't find an answer in searches.  I do have a solution (shown below) that involves COALESCE on every non-key column, I'm wondering if there's a Dynamic TSQL routine, or perhaps a different way of forumulating the query that doesn't involve explicitly naming all the columns.

I have two tables, "targetTable" and "deltaTable", that have a the same field names and types.  Both have a unique key, "id".

Deltatable has data that has changed for a corresponding row in targetTable.  Any column where the value hasn't changed is null.  I want to update the columns in the targetTable that have non-null values in the corresponding row of the deltaTable.  DetlaTable.id is guaranteed to exist in TargetTable.id, and I never want to update a field to NULL.

I'm using SQL Server 2005 (which doesn't have the merge statement, not that I know it would help).

So if a targetTable row looks like

```
  id | name    |  dob        | next_appt
  5    Bill       1-1-2012   | 3-3-2015
```

and a deltaTable row looks like

```
  id | name     | dob        | next_appt
  5  | NULL     | NULL       | 4-4-2015
```

I want targetTable updated to

```
  id | name    |  dob        | next_appt
  5    Bill       1-1-2012   | 4-4-2015
```

What I have now that I want to improve on is:

```
UPDATE target
SET target.colA = COALESCE(delta.colA, target.colA),
    target.colN = COALESCE(delta.colN, target.colN)
FROM  delta JOIN target on delta.id = target.id
```

Comment: With both `UPDATE` and `MERGE`, you have to specify the columns you are updating.  You could build your string and execute it with `EXEC`, but that opens you up to the possiblity of SQL injections, difficult-to-maintain code and slow performance.  I'd say your query looks fine as-is.

Comment: I agree that the query looks fine.  You could build the query dynamically but I wouldn't consider it unless you had a compelling reason.

Comment: Thanks, littlebobbytables and narthring, I'll probably accept GilM's answer once I test it out, it's sort of a no-great-choice scenario.  A bunch of tables our department doesn't control the schema for but has to convert into, the scripts that do the conversion in a proprietary gui and copied for bunches of projects, might make the complexity of the dynamic query worthwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's a great idea, but if you really want to do it, you could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = N'UPDATE target SET
';
SELECT @sql = @sql + N'  target.'+QUOTENAME([name]) + ' = COALESCE(delta.' + QUOTENAME([name]) + ', target.' + QUOTENAME([name]) + '),
'
FROM sys.columns 
where object_id = object_id('target') AND [name] != 'id'
order by [column_id]

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql,LEN(@sql)-2,1,''); -- strip off the last commma
set @sql = @sql + 
'FROM delta 
JOIN target ON  delta.id = target.id'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thanks, that gets me started.